# How to get a specific entry from a custom ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, retrofit

I have an Android app that uses `Retrofit` to consume an API, puts JSON into a custom `ArrayList` and then populates a `ListView` by using a custom `ArrayAdapter`. This works as intended.

The `ListView` items display 3 of the 7 values available in the model I used. Now I wanted to make it so that upon clicking a list item, a new activity starts and displays a complete entry, with all the 7 values.

I made the list items clickable with `onItemClickListener` and made an `Intent` that starts the new Activity. This Activity has a couple of `TextView`'s that are there to house all the 7 values from a single entry. I made the JSON `ArrayList` parcelable and passed it as an Extra along with the `Intent`.

**The problem:**

I can populate `ListView`'s and `RecyclerView`'s alright, but I don't know how to extract JSON data that's under a specific index. `ArrayList.get(x)` doesn't work, because the object is custom and doesn't include that method, I think. Here's my `ArrayList` model:

```
public class ListModel implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("id")
private String idno;

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

@SerializedName("telno")
private String telno;

@SerializedName("street")
private String street;

@SerializedName("city")
private String city;

@SerializedName("hour")
private String hour;

@SerializedName("desc")
private String desc;


public ListModel(String idno,
                 String name,
                 String telno,
                 String street,
                 String city,
                 String hour,
                 String desc) {
    this.setIdno(idno);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setTelno(telno);
    this.setStreet(street);
    this.setCity(city);
    this.setHour(hour);
    this.setDesc(desc);
}

public String getIdno() {return idno;}
public void setIdno(String idno) {this.idno = idno;}

public String getName() {return name;}
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

public String getTelno() {return telno;}
public void setTelno(String telno) {this.telno = telno;}

public String getStreet() {return street;}
public void setStreet(String street) {this.street = street;}

public String getCity() {return city;}
public void setCity(String city) {this.city = city;}

public String getHour() {return hour;}
public void setHour(String hour) {this.hour = hour;}

public String getDesc() {return desc;}
public void setDesc(String desc) {this.desc = desc;}

// Parcel stuff after this
```

Also, here's a snippet of the JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Young","telno":"692-(371)616-8685","street":"96333 Anhalt Court","city":"Loen","hour":"18:38","desc":"Quisque id justo sit amet sapien dignissim vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;"},
 {"id":2,"name":"Fowler","telno":"46-(368)133-6356","street":"5 School Parkway","city":"Onsala","hour":"16:17","desc":"Proin leo odio, porttitor id, consequat in, consequat ut, nulla. Sed accumsan felis. Ut at dolor quis odio consequat varius."},
```

Here's the adapter:

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListModel> {


public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListModel> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ListModel listModel = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView hourTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hourTV);
    TextView idnoTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idnoTV);
    TextView nameTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);

    hourTV.setText(listModel.getHour());
    idnoTV.setText(listModel.getIdno());
    nameTV.setText(listModel.getName());

    return convertView;

}
```

}

Please let me know if any more code is needed. This is my first app, so please bear with me if I'm missing something obvious, or don't explain myself clearly enough.

Thank you.

**SOLUTION EDIT**

Here's a working result:

`MainActivity.java`

```
public ArrayList<ListModel> dataSource = new ArrayList<>();

// Retrofit fetches and parses JSON here.

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent detailViewIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailView.class);

            ListModel listModel = dataSource.get(position);
            detailViewIntent.putExtra("TAG", listModel);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("jsondata", listModel);
            detailViewIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(detailViewIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

`DetailView.class`

```
public class DetailView extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_view);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ListModel jsondata = bundle.getParcelable("jsondata");

    // Populate 7 TextViews using ListModel getters like so: 
    TextView hourTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hourTV);
    hourTV.setText(jsondata.getHour());
```

Comment: If I understand your problem.. What you are trying to achieve is open a new activity and display the whole response you are getting from retrofit? Right? Why do you need that json? I mean Retrofit maps the response for you, so you can simply share whole object instead of a json. If I am missing something, please post your list adapter too.

Comment: Let me rephrase: I want to expand upon only a specific entry. Say, the user clicks on a list item that has "ID:1, Young, Loen" in it. It starts a new activity with a couple of TextViews that say "ID:1, Young, 692-(371)616-8685, 96333(...)", etc. If I just jammed the whole retrofit response in there, wouldn't that mean all the other people from that JSON get included, too? I'm not sure if Retrofit iterates over that JSON and creates a separate ArrayList<Model> object for each person, or just packs everything into one ArrayList? I'm updating the question with my adapter, if it helps.

Comment: Please see the edited answer, I hope it will be more clear after reading this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - ListModel is not an custom `ArrayList`, it is just parcelable `Object`, that's why you cannot use `ArrayList.get(int)`.

Now back to the solution.
You have some ListView with an onClickListener, which may look like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // HANDLE CLICK
    }
});
```

In case you have some collection, lets say `List<ListModel>`, the `position` parameter is the one you need. The onClickLister should be:

```
private List<ListModel> listData;
....
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(...);
        // Get the object that has been clicked
        ListModel listModel = listData.get(position);
        // Pass it to your activity
        i.putExtra("TAG", listModel);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

If you have any questions or your code is different to this one, please free to ask me.

**EDIT**

> I'm not sure if Retrofit iterates over that JSON and creates a separate ArrayList object for each person

If you have successfully created a ListView from the code you posted, than one ListModel == one person. Thats the magic of Retrofit! 
Guess your json hierarchy is like this one:

```
[
    {"id":1, "name":"somename1",...},
    {"id":2, "name":"somename2",...},
    {"id":3, "name":"somename3",...}
]
```

Then retrofit takes each JSONObject and converts it into your object (ListModel)

> If I just jammed the whole retrofit response in there, wouldn't that mean all the other people from that JSON get included, too?

You wont pass whole retrofit response to that activity by doing

```
ListModel listModel = listModels.get(position);
```

As I said, one ListModel == one person. The whole retrofit response is not ListModel, but List (or whatever.. maybe ListModels if you require that from retrofit)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was enlightening. My code was similar, but I failed to single out the required ListModel part. I'll try implementing it when I have the chance and then edit the original question to be a bit clearer.

Comment: It works! You've pulled me out of a hole I've dug myself into during the last few days, thank you! I edited the question to include the working result. I guess the title would need to be changed, but I'm not sure how to properly name it.